# Why is this date between query failing?

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting this error message

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near  WHERE STR_TO_DATE(Game_Scheduled_Datetime,'%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN
>   '05/10/2005' AND ''  at line 1

Is this not how to use a varchar as a date?

Comment: Please, provide the full query.

Comment: We cant help you if you dont give us some code.

Comment: What is your Exact query. Please post it.

Comment: Apart from requiring the code, you should STR_TO_DATE the dates in the BETWEEN as they are now VARCHAR.

Comment: We need to see the whole query in order to help - but why not rewrite the date in proper sql format or format the constant to suit the variable? Either way, on a big table it's going to be appreciably faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there are 2 problems in your query.

1. > ... WHERE STR_TO_DATE(Game_Scheduled_Datetime,'%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN ...

   Here you need to specify the column in your table which should be checked.  So you need sth. like

   > ... WHERE my_date BETWEEN ...

   Where my_date is a column in your table.
2. > BETWEEN '05/10/2005' AND ''

   you are missing the second (To) parameter. You would need sth. like

   ```
   SELECT * FROM `your_table` WHERE my_date  BETWEEN "2013-01-05 00:00:00" AND "2013-06-05 00:00:00"
   ```